# Automatically adding a slash at the end of a url

Tags: python, django, url-routing, django-urls

I've got all urls configured correctly, with a trailing slash. Now, whenever I visit a correct url that has no trailing slash, I get the "homepage" (since this is the page to show when a url is wrong). This is a pain in the ass since the url is 'somewhat' correct.

I've tried to explicitly enable this with `APPEND_SLASH = True` in the settings.py but without any success. I'm still in the development phase so no weird rewrite rules from a server.

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `APPEND_SLASH` will only be triggered if all urls fail. So if you have a "wildcard" path that redirects to the homepage, that will not work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! That is actually very helpfull, I didn't know that and neither is it written down in the documentation.

Comment: it is, the documentation says "*When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.*".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well, my Homepage was literally '', which is nothing. I've changed it to 'main/' and it immediatly worked. After that, I've changed it back to '' and it still seemed to work. I'm quite sure that these were the only 2 states since I just ctrl+z'ed until no changes could be undone.... This is weird behaviour

Comment: I'm currently comparing the 2 versions, since I have one staging server, a local testserver and a production server. There are literally no differences between the staging and the local server. :\